# Hiding a div with the same class as another using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Basically, I would like to accomplish the following with jQuery:

```
    <div class="120 most-voted">
       <!-- DON'T HIDE THIS DIV -->
    </div>


    <div class="110 voted">
       <!-- some stuff here -->
    </div>

    <div class="120 voted">
       <!-- hide this div with class '120' since there's already 
            another div with class '120' at the top -->
    </div>

    <div class="23 voted">
       <!-- some stuff here -->
    </div>
```

**EDIT: The numbers are dynamically generated by a PHP function:**

```
    <?php $postid = get_the_ID(); // capture the id ?>

    <div id="<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="most-voted">
```

I don't want to hide the div at the top.

Any suggestions (I don't mind wrapping another div in the div at the top to accomplish this result)?

Comment: You shouldn't *have* any elements with the same ID. That's the point of the `id` attribute. If you need to do things with a bunch of related elements, try using a class rather than an ID.

Comment: @Matt Gibson OK I changed it for a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make the first div with class "v120" visible and all others hidden:

```
var theClass = "v120";
$("div." + theClass).first().show().end().not(":first").hide();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/oreho6/3)

(I added the "v" to "120" because I wasn't sure whether "120" is a valid CSS class.)

How that works:

1. Find all `div`s with the class - `$()`.
2. Reduce that set temporarily to the first match - [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
3. [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) that one (in case it used to be hidden)
4. End the temporary reduction of the set - [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)
5. Reduce the set to only the matches that *aren't* the first - [`.not(":first")`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)
6. [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) them

Comment: Thanks! But when you said all other, you mean all other divs with class v120, or all other divs regardless of the class? I just want to hide the second div with class v120.

Comment: @alexchenco: All other divs with class "v120". Updated the example to demonstrate that.

Comment: @alexchenco: Added an explanation as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its not valid html, the id must be unique within the document

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Use rel attributes instead of IDs. Then use selector like:

```
$('div.voted[rel=110]')
```

Comment: `div` doesn't have a `rel` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element For elements that do (`a`, `area`, `link`), it defines the relationship of this *document* to another *document*, not this element to another element or an abstract concept like "votes".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same div, you should conceder using a class attribute since double id is not allowed.

```
 <div class="most-voted id_120">
   <!-- some stuff here -->
</div>


<div  class="voted id_110">
   <!-- some stuff here -->
</div>

<div  class="voted id_120">
   <!-- hide this div with id 120 since its already 
        at the top in the div with class most-voted -->
</div>

<div  class="voted id_100">
   <!-- some stuff here -->
</div>
```

use this to locate the first on http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/